Multiple-stage op-amp signal distortion
To test it - I changed the gain to be 5 instead of 100, but it still didn't seem to work as expected. Is there anything wrong with the way I am coupling the two stages?
I am designing a two-stage op-amp circuit for amplifying a 1 MHz signal, intending for each stage to provide an amplification factor of 100. Initially, I experimented with a single-stage op-amp and it seemed to work fine. However, when I tried to link two stages together, the output showed considerable distortion of the input signal. In addition, when the amplitude of the input signal is below a certain level (around 10 mVpp), my oscilloscope displays only a DC level with no AC component.
I would appreciate feedback on what I did wrong to cause the distortion when cascading two op-amp stages and how this might be fixed.
I use of a single-supply op-amp, so there is a biasing circuit to offset the input signal. The input waveform is generated by a waveform generator, and output is connected to an oscilloscope, both are using BNC to SMA cables.
The Op-amp is LT6200 with a GBP of 160 MHz.
Single-stage circuit:

Oscilloscope capture, input signal 1MHz at 6mVpp:

2-stage circuit:

Oscilloscope capture, input signal 1MHz at 15mVpp:

Oscilloscope capture, input signal 1MHz at 10mVpp:


If each stage amplifies by 100, 10mV input will make 100V output. Sounds wrong. How about trying 0.1mV signal?

And a DC blocking capacitor at the input is required.

To test it - I changed the gain to be 5 instead of 100, but it still didn't seem to work as expected. Is there anything wrong with the way I am coupling the two stages?

In the second schematic with two stages: Connect the input signal with biasing to the + input, not the - input. Another thing, which isn't why you are having problems, ground symbols in a properly drawn schematic point downwards, not upwards or sideways.

@tmuuuu I'm sorry but once you have received answers pointing out your mistakes you should not update your post like that. I have rolled it back to how it was. In future, on new posts, be very accurate about what you present. Nobody making an answer can be expected to know what your problem is other than by analysing the presented information and doing so in good faith.

It's not the coupling, it is the DC operating point.
In the first schematic, the inverting input is referenced to GND, while the non-inverting input is referenced to Vcc/2.  The opamp is trying to multiply that difference by 100, and saturating.
UPDATE:
Here is a concept schematic showing input, output, and interstage coupling, plus two different methods for establishing the DC operating point in a single-supply circuit.  There is no power supply decoupling, the circuit gains probably are too low, and the opamps shown were example parts grabbed from my design library.  All component values are approximate, and should be adjusted for the actual circuit requirements.

For the U1 stage, R2, R3, and R4 set the operating point as in your schematic.  To prevent this network from lowering the input impedance of the circuit and causing an impedance mismatch, the parallel combination of R2 and R3, plus R4, should be at least 100x R1.
In the U2 stage, the Thevenin equivalent of R7 and R8 is a 5 K resistor tied to a voltage source equal to Vcc/2.  The lower the impedance, the better for noise performance.  However, the lower the impedance, the more U1 has to work to drive it.  This is a tradeoff based on the gain and output characteristics of U1.  As long as the two amplifier stages are not widely separated, this impedance does not have to be a controlled value.
To be clear, either bias circuit will work in either location.
C4 and C6 solve the problem.  They are open circuits at DC, reducing both  stage gains to 1.  Thus, whatever DC is at the non-inverting input is the DC value at the output.  Basically, they charge up to the DC level at the non-inv input, and are short circuits at the operating frequencies of interest.  This was the main error in the first schematic.
Update update: Corrected component values.
To select the values for C4 and C6, first select the feedback resistors for the desired gain.  Then, C4 and C6 can be calculated such that their impedance at the lowest frequency of interest is at least 100x smaller than R6 and R10.
Note that the two stage gains do not have to be equal.

Could you elaborate? When I tested the first circuit the results seemed to be correct.
When I tested the pins with no AC input, the V+ and V- and Vout seemed to be all biased at Vcc/2

The non-inverting input isn't referenced to Vcc/2 if whatever is driving the coax connector is referenced to ground.  The input voltage will just overpower the the bias network.  I think you have to correct both that and the issue pointed out by @AnalogKid to get the circuit working.

Thank you both for your response, but I have a difficult time understanding where I went wrong.
I am trying to implement the single supply biasing here
https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Operational_Amplifiers_and_Linear_Integrated_Circuits_-Theory_and_Application%28Fiore%29/04%3A_Basic_Op_Amp_Circuits/4.03%3A_Single_Supply_Biasing
I don't understand the part about referencing to Vcc/2 and referengin to ground, my input is AC signal centered at 0V level, but I want to offset it to be centered at VCC/2 for my single-supply op-amp.

See the Updates in the answer.

You have an open circuit on pin 3: -

This will prevent it working but, there may be other errors.
You may also need to check the shutdown pin is driven to the power rail.

Ooops, sorry, made a mistake while copying the schematics out... corrected in the original post, really sorry for the oversight.
The input is indeed connected to the V+ side.

@tmuuuu I'm sorry but once you have received answers pointing out your mistakes you should not update your post like that. I have rolled it back to how it was. In future, on new posts, be very accurate about what you present. Nobody making an answer can be expected to know what your problem is other than by analysing the presented information and doing so in good faith.
